# Getting FieldErrors from an ObjectError from a BindingResult

Tags: spring, validation, error-handling

I'm trying to log errors returned to a controller from a validator class, but I'm only getting the ObjectError returned, which means I cannot log more specific information in my logger.

Ex:

```
    public void logErrors(BindingResult bindingResult){
        for (Object object : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
            if (object instanceof ObjectError) {
                ObjectError objectError = (ObjectError) object;
                logger.error("Bad request for " + ((FieldError) objectError).getField() + " of " + objectError.getObjectName() + " in myClass");
            }
            if (object instanceof FieldError) {
                FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;
                logger.error("Bad request for " + fieldError.getCode() + " of " + fieldError.getObjectName() + " in myClass");
            }
        }
}
```

This works as intended when receiving a fieldError, but trying to handle an ObjectError hasn't worked. As you can see above (and as was suggested in other threads), casting the ObjectError to a FieldError is suggested, but it won't work currently, stating that I cannot case an ObjectError to FieldError. Is there another way to accomplish what I'm looking for? Thanks!

edit: let me clarify by showing my validator class method, I'm testing by entering an ID that should throw a min error.

```
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) target;

        if(myCLass.getId() < 1000 || myClass.getId() > 100000) {
            errors.reject("myClass", "Id[must be between 1000 and 100000");
        }
    }
```

Simplified version of MyClass (its a POJO):

```
public class MyClass {

    private Long Id;

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FieldError](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html) is a subclass of [ObjectError](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html), therefore you cannot cast `ObjectError` to `FieldError`.

With your current `for` loop you will get duplicate logs for `FieldError` since both `if` statements will evaluate to `true`. You could rewrite your for loop as follows:

```
public void logErrors(BindingResult bindingResult){
    for (ObjectError objectError : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
        if (objectError instanceof FieldError) {
            FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) objectError;
            logger.error(...); // log field error
        }
        else {
            logger.error(...); // log object error
        }
    }
}
```

If you are only interested in FieldErrors, there is also `getFieldErrors()` method you could use instead of `getAllErrors()`.

**Edit:**
Use `rejectValue()` instead of `reject()` to generate a field error.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My issue is that when I am receiving an ObjectError, I'm not able to access the specific field of the object causing the error. So my logger's output is more vague than I would prefer (it'll tell me the class type causing the error, not the field within the class). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hm. I initially tried that but was receiving this:     "errorMessage": "Invalid property '<id>' of bean class [MyClass]: Bean property '<id>' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?" 

And yes, the getter/setter parameters match. Any easy fix for this?

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `rejectValue()`? It should be something like this: `errors.rejectValue("id", "error.invalid.id", "Id must be between 1000 and 100000");`

Comment: ive tried multiple variations of this:           errors.rejectValue("myClass", "Id[must be between 1000 and 100000");

I tried one like yours and I get the same response.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `MyClass`?

Comment: It's because the field name `Id` in `MyClass` is capitalised.. If you change `Id` to `id` it should work.

Comment: ah, that was just a typo (its not actually called simply id in my codebase). its a camel case, so basically "private Long myClassId". Would anything there make a difference?

Comment: oh F. haha I think I caught it. one sec. edit: awesome! got it. thanks for all the help!